# R - Scatter chart increase the legend breakdown of point size graph

Tags: r, charts, scatter-plot

I have tried various way to increase the legend breakdown of point size but failed to do that.

Here is the cases:
I  use the code below to generate the chart in the picture

```
p + geom_point(aes(size=order_items_go_through, shape=average_time_group)) +
    scale_size(range = c(3,8))
```

[image: Sample chart]

The issues is it is too generic legend while I want to break them down by:

- 200,000
- 150,000
- 100,000
- 50,000
- 25,000
- 10,000
- 1,000

How can I do that, and for the friendliness, how can I specify the display of number legend in format above.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It sounds like setting `breaks` in `scale_size` is what you are trying to do.  Have you tried that?  You can then change how the labels are displayed using `labels`.  See the help page for `continuous_scale` for more info on these arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to aosmith, I found the way to do it!

So here is the answer to my questions:

```
plot + scale_size_continuous(breaks=c(100,1000,2500,5000,10000,20000), 
                              labels=c('100','1,000','2,500','5000','10,000','20,000'),
                              range=c(1,20))
```

I add some exception to my code above, in hear if there is no data for the scale, it will not displaying as a legend. This is very good to not confuse reader.

[image]